# Junit test does not replace placeHolders

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, pom.xml

I have this configuration class in a maven project:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Configuration
public class SmsConfig {

    @Value("${sms.domainId}")
    private String domainId;

    @Value("${sms.gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;

    @Value("${sms.cmd}")
    private String cmd;

    @Value("${sms.login}")
    private String login;

    @Value("${sms.passwd}")
    private String passwd;

}
```

I have this service class in a Spring project:

```
Service("smsService")
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl implements SmsService {

    private final SmsConfig smsConfig;

    public AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl(SmsConfig smsConfig) {
        this.smsConfig = smsConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendSMS(String msg, String to) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

and this Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SmsConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("smsService")
    private AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl smsService;

    @Test
    public void testSendSMS() throws Exception {
        smsService.sendSMS("this is a test", "+34776498");
    }

}
```

on IntelliJ IDEA it seems that the values on the config class are set correctly

[image]

but when I run the test Junit test does not replace placeHolders

```
5:25:40.009 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{ "credentials":{"domainId":"${sms.domainId}","login":"${sms.login}","passwd":"${sms.passwd}"},"destination":["32470855126"], "message":{"msg":"this is a test","concat":"true", "encoding":"unicode"} }] as "application/json"
```

and here my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have right set of maven pom for lombok compilation?

Comment: Your POM isn't useful here; what does your application.properties and application-test.properties actually hold? (If Lombok was broken, nothing would compile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SmsConfig.class, AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImplTest {
..
}
```